# Stop execution of event listener if initial event returns false

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can we stop execution of event listener if initial event returns false?

Lets say for example:-

```
<form id="cForm" name="cForm" method="post" onsubmit="return validate();">
...
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" >
    function validate() {
        return false;            
    }

    $("#cForm").submit(function() {
        // if validate() returns false do not execute this
    });
</script>
```

I tried this:

```
var form = document.getElementById('cForm');
var oldEvent = form.onsubmit;
form.onsubmit = function() {
    return oldEvent && alert("test");
};
```

But it always alerts "test".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

- Remove the `onsubmit` attribute from your `form` first, as you have already binded a **jQuery** `submit` event to it.
- Next add the code for the validation like below inside the `submit` method.

**JS:**

```
$("#cForm").submit(function () {
    // if validate() returns false do not execute this
    if (!validate()) return false;
});
```

**UPDATE**

Based on your requirement, you can do this:

```
$("#cForm").submit(function () {
    var status = true;

    try {
        status = this["onsubmit"]();
        if (typeof (status) === "undefined") status = true;
    } catch (e) {
        status = true;
    }

    return status && alert("test");
});
```

Comment: I can't change the on submit attribute, I need a solution from within the event listener..

Answer (score 1):

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/oCOmuji/2/edit)**

```
<form id="cForm" name="cForm" method="post"></form>
```

```
function validate() {
   return false; // try with true      
}

$("#cForm").submit(function( e ) {
  if(!validate){
      e.preventDefault();
      alert('invalid...') ;
  }else{
     alert('VALID!!') ;
  }
});
```

**If you cannot change the inline `onsubmit`**

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/oCOmuji/3/edit)**

```
function validate() {  
  var test = true;

  if(test){
    alert('VALID!!!');
  }else{
    alert('invalid...');
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't change the on submit attribute, I need a solution from within the event listener..